# How to correct XY mirroring?

Tags: marlin, skr-v1.4

So I made a 3D printer from scratch. It is a RepStrap based on a Prusa i3 running Marlin 2.0.x.

It prints fine and accurate, but, The trouble is that the XY plane is mirrored and I don't know how to solve this.

I'm using Marlin 2.0.x on an SKR 1.4 controller board.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure X = X and Y = Y. If possible hook up a [console](/q/10573) or a software application that communicates with the printer, e.g. Pronterface (PrintRun suite) or Repetier Host. The latter options allow for graphical interfacing with the printer; homing, movement, etc.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure that you have correctly identified the X and Y axes, and that the stepper motors (and end-stop switches) are connected to the correct ports. The hot end moves on the X-axis, and the bed moves on the Y-axis. If you connect the X and Y motors the wrong way round, you will get reversed text.

If the X and Y motors are connected to the correct ports, you may need to invert the motor directions in firmware. There are `#define` statements to allow you to do this.

Comment: Oh I see, turn the wires around AND invert in Marlin?! That makes sense! Will try! thanks!

Comment: No. Swap the cables if they are connected to the wrong ports (this is a common error). Otherwise, you will have to change the firmware.

Comment: @DennisDecoene You only need to do "AND" if you need to flip the connectors 180° in the same port (then the endstop is in the wrong direction).